# Notify posters when questions merged

Tags: feature-request, notifications, recent-activity, merged-questions

I just found that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25872/how-would-you-motivate-your-colleagues-to-join-stackoverflow/25883#25883) had been merged with another, and I had two similar answers on it.  I've now deleted the extra answer, but it's probably been that way a while.

**Edited (because of George's great answer):** Could we have a notification in the response envelope/recent activity for all those users whose questions have been merged, and those users with answers on that question, so that they could check that everything was still copacetic?

Comment: Feature would work ok I guess, but remember not everyone uses the email notifications.

Comment: I meant sending an email to the email that people register with the site when they join up, not the email notificiations per post (which I don't use either).

Comment: @Lance: Not all registrations require an email. AOL openId is an example.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I figured they had an email for everyone in some fashion.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: How often does this even happen?

Comment: I have no idea, that's the problem.  I could have more of these dupes floating around and not even realize it.

Comment: FWIW, you should be able to see it in your answers list - a duplicate answer would show up with (2) after it.

Comment: For now I'm going to start checking that every so often.

Comment: Related (on [meta.ubuntu.se]): [Can we get a notice that questions we answered were merged?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7242/can-we-get-a-notice-that-questions-we-answered-were-merged)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'd be better to have a site notification; much in the same way you're notified when someone answers your question or comments on your answer.

Something like:

> Your Answer has been merged to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8/).

Comment: That's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't yet notify, but the merge process has been improved.

We now handle question merging in a much more sane way -- both questions are retained, one is a stub, and all answers are migrated into the merged question. If the stub is deleted, we 301 redirect to the merge target.