# Merging questions doesn't notify the OP of new answers

Tags: feature-request, notifications, merged-questions

**Actual behaviour:**
When the answer is merged, there is no way for the OP to know whether there are any new answers to his question because he is not notified.

**Expected behaviour:**
When an answer from the duplicate question is merged, the OP is notified of the new answers to his question thereby, allowing the OP to evaluate the new answers and marking the best answer accordingly (where necessary).

---

**Case in point:**
I didn't know I had merged answers to one of my [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-the-nautilus-bookmarks) until I accidentally stumbled across the question due to notification of a new answer earlier yesterday. I don't ever remember being notified of the additional answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify posters when questions merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26932/notify-posters-when-questions-merged)

Comment: @Manishearth It's different. I am talking about the person who asked the original question. The link is about the person whose answers got moved. Or I might have misinterpreted.

Comment: Its wider--it's asking for notifications for the asker _and_ the answerers

Comment: @Manishearth I am not convinced it is the same thing. My problem is, if there are new answers to my question (incoming) because of the merge, I don't get notified. I don't have much of an issue if my question gets merged and the answer are moved out (outgoing).

Comment: Aah, I see. Your title threw me off, improved.